# What is the mrxdav.sys file and what file system is it used for?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, filesystems

I'm looking to know more about the mrxdav.sys file on Windows machines, and what is the difference between it and ntfs.sys, cdfs.sys or fat.sys?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mrxdav.sys is the Windows WebDAV Mini-redirector driver.

WebDAV (stands for Distributed Authorizing and Versioning) is an extension to HTTP that is used for managing and collaboratively editing documents across the internet.

If you use Process Explorer, and highlight the "System" process, and open the DLL view, it will list all of the drivers that you currently have loaded.  Unless you have recently used a WebDAV service, you will not see mrxdav.sys loaded.

Now open a Run prompt by hitting Win+R, and type `\\live.sysinternals.com\tools`. After this Explorer window opens, which will resemble a file share but is actually WebDAV over the internet, you will see mrxdav.sys has magically been loaded.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't think I would have gotten to that answer by myself